# Getting an item from an ArrayList, within another ArrayList in Java?(Board wants to get a player within a location)

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, nested

Its for a monopoly type game in Java.
I want to know how i can get a specific player by their id, it goes through an array list of locations on the board, checks each one's arrayList for that particular player.

```
public class Board 


private ArrayList<Location> AllLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
public Player getPlayer(int pl){
int index = 0;
     for(Location temp : AllLocations)
    {
        if(temp.getPlayerId() == pl)
        {return temp;}
    }

    return null;

}
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Location {
private ArrayList<Player> Players = new ArrayList<Player>();

public Player getPlayerId (int id) {

    int index = 0;
     for(Player temp : Players)
    {
        if(temp.getId() == id)
        {return temp;}
        else
        {return null;}
    }

    return null;
}


}
```

---

```
public class Player {

public int getId() {

    return PlayerId;
}

}
```

I just want to get it so i can find out where player with iD 1, is for example, where they are on the board.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have a list of location and having to search for players based on id.  Add a location variable to the player object so that the Player always knowns where it is located.

Unrelated, using temp as your variable name in the for loops makes the code hard to read.  I would suggest a more descriptive name like 'player' or 'location'.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Location class shouldn't contains list of players on it. In mosts cases this list will be empty, so it's pointless. Consider adding a location variable to the player, or introducing some kind of game controller class, that connects players with their locations.

Answer (score 0):

You should have (in your board or game) a List with all the players (indexed by ID) - alternatively a Map, if your IDs are not consecutively. They don't really change independently of the game, so no point in searching them always.